# Lambda using kinesis stream not working when in vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda job that works fine until I put it in a VPC, it seems to stop reading the kinesis stream as soon as that is done and works again when I put it in no VPC. Anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Need some more details about your network configuration/possible AWS Organization restrictions. One thing to note is when you are running your Lambda in VPC mode, it has a security group associated. Can the group talk to everything it needs to, and is it being received on the other end?

Answer (score 1):

For lambda to work properly in VPC, you need to add `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` managed policy to your function's execution role.

Also it needs to be remembered that lambda in your vpc [does not have access to Internet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, it does not have access to the internet unless your VPC provides access.

To enable access to public kinesis endpoints:

> To give your function access to the internet, route outbound traffic to a NAT gateway in a public subnet. The NAT gateway has a public IP address and can connect to the internet through the VPC's internet gateway.

Alternatively, can setup [VPC interface endpoints to access kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/vpc.html) without going to the internet.

Hope this will be helpful.